# Problemas na exibição de imagem vindas do Firebase Storage / Hosting usando o Nextjs

Tags: react, firebase, next.js

Flaa pessoal, estou apamanhando há algumas horinhas para tentar entender porque raios a image `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/site-vofstudio.appspot.com/o/structure%2Fvercel.svg?alt=media&token=8cc0db35-06f0-4781-ae5c-4d7ef222650e` é exibida localmente, porém não está sendo impressa na página em produção.

Usei como guia o repo `https://github.com/ankeshs/next-firebase-boilerplate`, fiz algumas atualizações e atualizei os arquivos para o padrão vindos do `yarn create next-app`.

Adicionei ao arquivo `next.config.js` as infos:

```
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    formats: [
      'image/avif',
      'image/webp'
    ],
    domains: [
      'firebasestorage.googleapis.com',
      'site-vofstudio.appspot.com'
    ]
  }
```

e na importação da imagem mantive como:

`<Image src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/site-vofstudio.appspot.com/o/structure%2Fvercel.svg?alt=media&token=8cc0db35-06f0-4781-ae5c-4d7ef222650e" alt="Pinguen Linux" width={104} height={120} blurDataURL="data:..." placeholder="blur" automatically provided />`

Localmente, está tudo em ordem, porém em produção, a imagem não carrega.

Alguém pode me ajudar ou sabe qual a forma mais eficaz para exibir a imagem em prod?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: @Comunidade está tudo em ordem com a pergunta e sua descrição! ;)